Name of the movie - something to do with "island" with Bad Guy who dips his ring in blood and leaves mark on victims' forehead
I've been trying to find this movie that I saw on TV in early/mid 80s. I think the movie is from 70s, or early 80s at most. I've tried extensive keyword searches on IMDB, but I can't find it.
The story is set in 18th/19th century, either in the Pacific or the Caribbean.
It is told as a flashback by the Good Guy who's sitting in jail. It begins with the Bad Guy arriving on a ship to a small island and massacring the natives and kidnapping the Good Guy's Girl. The Bad Guy's signature is that he dips his ring in victim's blood and leaves the seal of the raven/crow/bird on their forehead. The bird is also the symbol of his ship (which I vaguely recall as being white).
Most of the rest of the movie is the Good Guy trying to find him and rescue his Girl. The other bit I remember is that Girl's somehow captured by (or given to) some savages who try to sacrifice her by tying her to a cross of some sorts and lowering her into the fire. I remember that scene with Girl tied up in the cross and being lowered from the rock into the fire as the title scene when the ad breaks came up, so that was probably an important scene or maybe even from the movie poster.
I can't remember what happens next but the last part is the Good Guy getting sprung from the jail by his friends (a horse or a donkey is somehow involved in the rescue) and then sailing away with the Girl on that same white ship.
It's an English-language movie. I can't remember what the Girl looks like (other than white, long hair, which doesn't narrow it down) - saw it 30 years ago. There would have been nudity and violence. Again, the Bad Guy killing people, dipping his ring in their blood and marking their forehead is relatively graphic, though I don't remember it being excessive. Think Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom type of thing. I don't think it was a kiddie movie.
Any ideas?

Hints? Like, English language movie? What does the Girl look like? Is there nudity and/or graphic violence, or is it more a kiddie thing?

It's an English-language movie.
I can't remember what the Girl looks like (other than white, long hair, which doesn't narrow it down) - saw it 30 years ago.
There would have been nudity and violence. Again, the Bad Guy killing people, dipping his ring in their blood and marking their forehead is relatively graphic, though I don't remember it being excessive. Think Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom type of thing.
I don't think it was a kiddie movie.

You're looking for Nate and Hayes (AKA Savage Islands), a somewhat Indiana Jones-esque pirate film from 1983 with Tommy Lee Jones.

The film tells the story of missionary Nathaniel "Nate" Williamsen (O'Keefe), taken to an island mission with his fiancee Sophie (Seagrove). Their ship, the Rona, is captained by the roguish Bully Hayes (Jones), who also takes a liking to Sophie. When Sophie is kidnapped by slave trader Ben Pease (Max Phipps), "Nate" teams with Hayes in order to find her.

The plot unfolds as a series of flashbacks Hayes has in prison. All the other things are there too: Sophie almost sacrificed by natives, the villain leaving a blackbird mark on victims' foreheads etc. Here are the first few minutes:




That is most definitely it. Thank you so much for find it for me!
